# Creating a recent feed using php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i am trying to create a recent activity feed which displays records from a mysql database and automatically cycles through the different records.

i have the following code:

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#datas {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.data {
    display: none;
}

-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
    get_data();
setInterval('get_data()', 5000);
});

function get_data() {
    $.post('data2.php', function(response) {
        $el = $('<div></div>').attr('class', 'data').html(response);
        $('#datas').prepend($el);
        count = $('#datas .data').length;
        if(count > 5) {
            $('#datas .data').last().remove();
        }
        height = $el.height()+'px';
        $el.css({'opacity': 0, 'display': 'block', 'height':     '0px'}).animate({height: height }, 500, function() {
                $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
        })
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>test page</h2>

<div id="datas">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can any body help direct me to the PHP I would need for data2.php to display one set of data at a time preferably examples and tutorials to guide me so i can learn and improve my coding better.

Thanks

K

Comment: So we're just supposed magically know what your database structure is and what data should be output?

Comment: Sorry my mistake a mysql database and looking to output stuff like name, details and date ect. I just need the basic info to get started so i can take it from there

Answer (score 1):

One way to go would be to maintain a 'mostRecentID' variable in javascript that holds the id of the most recent record.  Then, when you post to data2.php post the mostRecentID as well.

```
$.post('data2.php', {mostRecentID: mostRecentID}, function(response) ...
```

In data2.php you will then need to use the $_POST['mostRecentID'] variable in your query to the database.  You should be able at that point to select just the records since mostRecentID.  Something sorta like:

```
<?php
// cast our id as integer
$mostRecentID = (int) $_POST['mostRecentID'];

// connect to your database here
//....

// prep the query
$sql = sprintf("SELECT id, title, content FROM yourTable  
                WHERE id > '%c'",
                mysql_real_escape_string($mostRecentID));  

// run the query and handle your results
//....
?>
```

Comment: are you able to expand on this a bit...sorry for being a noob i am still learning most of this stuff

Comment: @Kyle Expanded on it a bit.  Hopefully this gives you an idea of how to get there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at the tutorials at w3schools.com. They have several tutorials covering PHP from basic to advanced, and also PHP in combination with MySQL, XML and AJAX.

You probably need the PHP - AJAX and MySQL http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp tutorial for your code sample, since it uses the jQuery .post() function to retrieve data from the data2.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, I made one 'log system' using PHP And Jquery(Ajax). The difference is thatI am not reading a database, but a file.log.

Take a look:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="log_box">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The JS:

```
var lastSize = 0;

$(function(){
    myInterval = setInterval(function() {
        doSomething();
    }, "1000" );

});     

    function doSomething(){
            request = $.ajax({
                type: "HEAD",
                url: 'log.txt?NC='+(new Date()).getTime(),
                success: function () {
                    actualSize = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length");

                    if(actualSize>lastSize){
                        $.getJSON('script.php',{},function(data){
                            var line = "<p>"+data+"</p>";
                            $(line).appendTo('#log_box');
                            console.log(line);
                        });     
                        lastSize = actualSize;
                     } else {
                        console.log('espera');
                     }
                }
            });
    }
```

BackEnd in PHP:

```
<?php
function tail($filePath){
    $line = '';

    $file = fopen($filePath, 'r');
    $cursor = -1;

    fseek($file, $cursor, SEEK_END);
    $char = fgetc($file);

    while ($char === "\n" || $char === "\r") {
        fseek($file, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
        $char = fgetc($file);
    }

    while ($char !== false && $char !== "\n" && $char !== "\r") {
        $line = $char . $line;
        fseek($file, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
        $char = fgetc($file);
    }
    return $line;
}

//$data = tail('../sistemapac/data/logs/2011-09-30.log');
$data = tail('log.txt');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

The Result is a HTMl page reloading in realtime with the log.

C ya!